# How to display an object that with multiple parameters without a getter?

Tags: java, arraylist

In this homework of mine, in my main I have this line:

```
Lec.addStudent( "James" , "A1" , "BICT" );
```

In another class called LectureRoom:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LectureRoom{

    private String courseName;
    private String roomNumber;
    private String Lecturer;    
    private ArrayList <Student> studentList;

    public LectureRoom(String roomNumber , String courseName , String Lecturer)
    {
        this.courseName=courseName;
        this.roomNumber=roomNumber;
        this.Lecturer = Lecturer;
        this.studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public void printStudents(){

        System.out.println(studentList);

    }

    public void addStudent(String name, String id, String major)
    {
        Student s = new Student(name, id , major);
        studentList.add(s);
    }            

    public ArrayList<Student> getStudentsByMajor(String major)
    {
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Student student : studentList) {
            if (student.getMajor().equals(major))
                students.add(student);
        }

        return students;
    }
```

The outcome is to be:

> Adding:James, A1, BICT

Normally, with a getter I would:

```
System.out.println("Adding:" + getStudentName() + ", " + getID() + ", " + getMajor() );
```

However in this case in method `addStudent`, I have created an object called "s" where it stores the name of the student, id and major.

Suppose I want to print all these 3 in a line, how can I do so?

I tried these in printStudents() method

1)  `System.out.println(studentList);`

2) `for(Student studentdetails : studentList) 
        {
             System.out.println(studentdetails);
        }`

but both returned-

> [Student@bf5743]

What is this error called and how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Override toString method

Comment: In some hours the whole homework will be done by s.o. one answer at a time.. :/

Comment: Sorry @RC.! How many times can I ask a day? I really did try and overriding is something new to me that isn't taught in the lectures yet.

Comment: +1 For a well formatted question with all required information provided.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Override `toString` method in your class, and

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return String.format();// print your desired format.
}
```

Using `System.out.println(obj)` directory will print use the default `toString` method which returns:

```
object.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(object.hashCode())
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up! Overriding is completely new to me. Btw is there any name for this error?

Comment: @SamLiew - It's not an error. When you `println()` most objects, it's class name, followed by it's hash code is printed. `[Student@bf5743]` is the class and hash code.

Comment: Its not an error, its just the default printing value for `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

There are more solutions for this problem, but a quite simple one, could be overriding the method `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return String.format("%s %s %s", s, id, major);
}
```

I'm assuming that your `Student` class has the attributes `s`, `id` and `major` that contain student name, id and major.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the API for the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class

Every class has Object as a superclass so your Student class under the covers basically extends Object at some point.

This is important as it means that every accessable method and field in Object is available to your Student class. You can see this in the ide you are using buy doing studentdetails. and see the list that comes up.

If methods in your hierarchy are not final and are accessable you can [override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) them and add your own implementation.